# What is the API for SONOS Playbar to Allow third party controlling Volume and Input Selection (Only)?

Tags: sonos

I only need to be able to control (over third party control system, Crestron) the volume (up, down, mute), select input (video or music) and ON/OFF for SONOS Playbar, Sub and two Play1 in order to achieve 5.1 surround sound.

I am not interested in controlling any of the other SONOS feature as I will use SONOS App for music services. I just need to ensure that my Crestron system can control volume regardless whether the active source is video (coming from the TV) or audio (coming from SONONS App) and also to be able to switch between audio and video sources.

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently have a public API available for Sonos control.  I will take this as input for future consideration back to the team.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UPnP specifications for RenderingControl, and use the volume/mute calls against the Playbar endpoint. Its easy. Selecting input is trickier: TV is simple, but for "music" you need to do a lot more work as you need to specify exactly what music, and Sonos support a gigantic array of options there.